# Can portable open office do this file conversion utility without installing Open office on my machine

Tags: openoffice.org

I want to do the file conversion from doc,xls to pdf using the utility of open office. But if I don't want to install open office and still want to use that utility with the help of portable open office then can this be done and how?

Regards,
Ankit

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can simply open the doc or xls file with the portable version of OpenOffice.org and simply use "File > Export as PDF" to get your PDF.

You might also want to try uploading the file to something like Google Docs which also lets you save as a PDF, or if you currently have Microsoft Office and are just looking to save your files as PDFs, you can just install one of the many PDF printers, for instance, [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/).